# Can't create a database using PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm new to databases and I have a problem, I looked in so many places to find solution to my problem. I'm using PostgreSQL Portable and when I launch the program it's telling me that it's creating first data base, but then this error shows up:

FATAL: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xea 0x70 0x6e

I tried reinstalling PostgreSQL and also checked the services looking for another database working, but it was futile. Can somebody help me with this?

EDIT:

There are no commands involved, I simply launched PostgreSQLPortable.exe, and normally it should create first database (worked on my friends PC), but instead the error which I wrote above shows up.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the code and commands you are using.

Comment: Sorry to mention that before, I didn't used any commands, I wrote explanation. Sorry for not providing more information, but it's really all I've got :/

Comment: What is your operating system user name?

Comment: "PostgreSQLPortable.exe"  What is that?  It is not a standard part of PostgreSQL.  Is it a third party client?  A third party fork?  Please provide a link.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/postgresqlportable/files/v9.6.1/PostgreSQLPortable_9.6.1_online.paf.exe/download
@jjanes, we were provided with this by our teacher, and my problem is the only case among everyone. You think the problem lies in this particular application?
Like I said before, sorry for lack of any knowlege in this field, I'm really green :/